# Error: Can not save config file in Linux

Tags: virtualbox, configure, selinux

I am trying to edit a configuration file so called `config` from /etc/selinux/config in Oracle linux. I have tried using gedit and with terminal but I still get the same error.

```
Error: Can't save. Permission Denied!
```

I am doing it all in a Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on Oracle Linux should be asked on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to follow:

- Go to /selinux and from file menu choose open in `terminal`
- Now when you are in terminal window type `su` and press enter. It will ask you for a `password`. Enter it.
- go to your /selinux directory use `cd` command (you may be aware of that)
- type `ls` to check whether `config` file is showing or not. If showing proceed further.
- type vi config (a vi editor with config file content will be opened)
- go to the area you want to make changes by pressing `i` on the keyboard. Edit your text.
- Press `Esc` and type `:wq` (colon with wq)

w - save

q - quit

Please do note that if you try to save from terminal file menu, it won't get saved. You must have to specify :wq to make changes to your file.

---

This is the way you can edit any configuration file in linux or unix.

Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks!